# RawTransaction stuck at the pending status endlessly

Tags: ethereum, web3js, erc20, ether

I've successfully pushed a rawTransaction to Ropsten network via infura. But, when I checked on EtherScan the corresponding transaction it kept showing the "pending" status endlessly, I noticed that the token transfer it looked strange. Please see the screen attached here.
The Token supposed to show CToken, instead of ERC20.

**Error!**
[image: Issue]

**Expected Result**
[image]

Comment: How did you send that tx? Using MetaMask?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin - I created a RawTransaction and signed with the private key and sent it to the Ropsten network by using web3 and ethersjs library.

Comment: Please provide more details such as the code of how you send the transaction